# ID standards for county identification for geomapping project?

Tags: d3.js

I'm looking at this cool D3 project that colors counties based on a variable:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606

I'm not sure what is being used as identification for the counties though, it doesn't seem to be a federal standard like FIPS. Can anyone point me to what these codes are called?

Comment: The 'id' element in both the tsv data, and topojson file are both indeed fips codes, the first two digits representing fips state, the last three fips county. This value is not zero padded, so that may cause some confusion.